# from one array, find the two array that map the value of elements

Tags: php, arrays

from one array, find the two array that map the value of elements
    have an array:

```
$A = Array ( [0] => 0;0 
               [1] => 0;1
               [2] => 1;0 )
```

Will get the new one like this:
I am going TODO something like this

```
    function split_map_arr($A){
      TODO
    }
```

function will return two array like this

```
        idxs_main=array(0,1)
        idxs_sub=array(array(0,1),
                       array(1)
                      )
```

How could I do this?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking, and your code is full of syntax errors. Fix them first, because it's hard to figure out what you intended.

Comment: can you reformulate the question I don't understand

Comment: @Palantir: Looks like pseudocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm deciphering your question correctly...

```
function split_map_arr($A){
  $idxs_main = array();
  $idxs_sub = array();
  foreach ($A as $a) {
    list($main, $sub) = explode(';',$a);
    if (array_key_exists($main, $idxs_main)) {
      $idxs_sub[array_search($main, $idxs_main)][] = $sub;
    } else {
      $idxs_main[][] = $main;
      $idxs_sub[][] = $sub;
    }
  }
  return array($idxs_main, $idxs_sub);
}

// usage
$A = array(0 => '0;0', 1 => '0;1', 2 => '1;0');
list($idxs_main, $idxs_sub) = split_map_arr($A);
```